# How to append Int array to file horizontally?

Tags: c#

I am trying to writ to a file horizontally the best i can do is write them to file vertically.

So Instead of printing to the file

```
1
2
```

They print to the file

```
1 2
```

Code

```
int[] test3 = new int[2];

        Random randNum3 = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < test3.Length; i++)
        {
            test3 = Enumerable.Range(1, 11).OrderBy(x => randNum3.NextDouble()).Take(2).ToArray();
        }

        int[] b = test3;
        int u;

        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
           // Console.Write("  " + b[i]  + " ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= b.Length - 2; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= b.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (b[i] > b[i + 1])
                {
                    u = b[i + 1];
                    b[i + 1] = b[i];
                    b[i] = u;
                }
            }
        }

        System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("C:\\Users\\Gandalf\\Desktop\\log.txt", b.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: 1) Open  file. 2) Seek to end. 3) Write data. 4) Close file.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use a bit more descriptive variable names. Where does `a` come from?

Comment: Apologies typo a should have been b, code corrected

Comment: It works fine, copied, run it and it appends the line correctly.... :/
Wait you want them to be added horizontally, ok... my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this will append the text "horizontally", instead of using `AppendAllLines`, we need to use `AppendAllText`, and the `IEnumerable` should be transformed to a `string`

```
int[] test3 = new int[11];

Random randNum3 = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < test3.Length; i++)
{
  test3 = Enumerable.Range(1, 11).OrderBy(x => 
    randNum3.NextDouble()).Take(2).ToArray();
}

int[] b = test3;
int u;

for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
{
  // Console.Write("  " + b[i]  + " ");
}
for (int j = 0; j <= b.Length - 2; j++)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= b.Length - 2; i++)
  {
    if (b[i] > b[i + 1])
    {
      u = b[i + 1];
      b[i + 1] = b[i];
      b[i] = u;
    }
  }
}

var write = $" {String.Join(" ", b.Select(x => x.ToString()))}";
File.AppendAllText("lines.txt", write);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a newline between each value. So

So use this to convert an array to a string:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, a);
```